# Java: Recursively writing to a file

Tags: java, recursion

Okay here is my situation:

I have a recursive function which is calculating and printing something to screen. Now I need that output to be to a file.

So I did this:

```
public void recursiveFn(int value) throws FileNotFoundException {
     recursiveFn(a);
     PrintWriter fileOP = new PrintWriter("file.txt")
     fileOp.printf(somevaluefromthisfunction)
}
```

Problem with this approach is, every time a call is made to that function recursively, a new file is being created and all the previous recursive calls data is being deleted.

Now my approach was to make the file create deflation outside this function. This is what I did:

```
public class MyClass {
      PrintWriter fileOP = new PrintWriter("file.txt") //line 2

      public void recursiveFn(int value) {
         recursiveFn(a);
         fileOp.printf(somevaluefromthisfunction)
    }
}
```

the issue with this? I'm getting this error: "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" at line 2. I lost almost 5% of my hair in the process of debugging this error!

Comment: If you use an IDE, it can auto fix this compilation error by having the callee handle this exception.  The debugger is only useful for code which compiles.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The IDE is also often useless for certain types of syntax or language errors.

Comment: @hexafraction or some IDEs are useless.  IntelliJ fixes almost all the syntax errors I get, though you still have to check the fix makes sense.  I constantly write code which doesn't compile because I know how IntelliJ will fix it form me as I type.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's a tool I prefer not to rely on, anyway. Fixing language errors like missing catches, or creating methods for me? That I appreciate. I prefer to make my own braces :)

Comment: @hexafraction Totally agree on the braces as I avoid them. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable initialization can throw an exception that you must handle.  Others have shown a few different ways to handle this.  The best, IMO, is to have a method that sets up everything the recursive method needs (like the PrintWriter) and then calls the recursive method.

```
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething(int value) {
        PrintWriter fileOP = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
        this.recursiveFn(value,fileOP);
    }
    public void recursiveFn(int value,PrintWriter fileOp) {
         int a = value + 1; // Or whatever
         recursiveFn(a,fileOp);
         fileOp.printf(somevaluefromthisfunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: @hexafraction I didn't downvote you, but I've got a feeling it has to do with the fact you didn't answer the question and provided syntactically incorrect code in your answer.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks You couldn't have downvoted me, as I'm not the author of this answer :) I wrote the other answer.

Comment: I was in the middle of posting and got cut off.  I am editing now.

Comment: @hexafraction Oopsies, my apologies!

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks No worries!

Answer (score 0):

Set the fileOP in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
      PrintWriter fileOP; //line 2

      public void recursiveFn(int value) {
         recursiveFn(a);
         fileOp.printf(somevaluefromthisfunction)
    }
    public MyClass(){
         try{
             fileOP = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             // do whatever you need to do to handle it
         }

    }
}
```

You can also pass the printwriter in the recursive definition:

```
public void recursiveFn(PrintWriter fOP, int a) throws FileNotFoundException {
    recursiveFn(fOP, a);

    fOP.printf(someFunc(a));
}
```

I'm guessing you'll want to tweak the recursion of the function a bit to be logical and not be infinite.